# IIS5.1 - 500 internal server error only in win7 clients

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, windows, iis

Hi guys today I've a strange problem I've a server in my job running IIS 5.1 and only the machines with windows 7 have the internal server error 500, all the other with windows XP pro works well this is driving me crazy.

I've already open the log and is inconclusive only show nameOfthepage.aspx -500 0 ....

tomorrow at work i will post the full log.

I've tried disable friendly pages etc but the error persists.

Some clues about this i appreciate.

Comment: Which log IIS or Windows application Event Log? Can you post full error message from the later?

Comment: at the moment i cant because i'am at home but tomorrow i will post, but i can advance the IIS event log only says something like this: nameOfthepage.aspx -500 0 the windows log i didn't check but tomorrow i will do

Comment: Problem solved was a cast string to date :D the log from windows event was a great help

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Yup, event log usually can provide a much more detailed .NET error